# How to use font-awesome from server

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I removed all @import rules from my style.css but then I lost all font-awesome icons that I had on my page.
I figured I can get them back if I copied the small section that my page was actually using from www.maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

The icons are still missing and I don't know how to get them back correctly in my css. I suppose I need to copy the actual icons as images to my images folder and link to them somehow via css, but I have not succeeded.

This the section that I copied:

```
/*!
/ *  Font Awesome 4.1.0 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome*/
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal
}
.fa {
display: inline-block;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
 }
 @-moz-keyframes spin {
 0% {
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg)
}
100% {
-moz-transform:rotate(359deg)
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)
}
100% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg)
}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
0% {
-o-transform:rotate(0deg)
}
100% {
-o-transform:rotate(359deg)
}
}
@keyframes spin {
0% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
transform:rotate(0deg)
}
100% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);
transform:rotate(359deg)
}
}
.fa-play-circle-o:before {
src:url(../images/play-icon.png)
}
.fa-arrow-circle-left:before {
content: "\f0a8"
}
.fa-arrow-circle-right:before {
content: "\f0a9"
}

.fa-angle-up:before {
content: "\f106"
}
```

I then even downloaded all the fonts in a zip folder and placed the unzipped folder on my server and tried to link to it, but without any result.

The missing icons are the video play icons in the bottom and the to-the-top arrow.
There are more on other pages but once I know how to link to them without @import I will figure out how to do the rest.

Any help is much appreciated.
Kim

Comment: Icons have _nothing_ to do with font awesome graphics.

Comment: What you are missing is to tell the browser where to get the font awesome from. You try to use it, but typically it is not installed on a client system, so you have to reference it inside your css. Please post your attempts to do so. Just telling "tried to link" does not help here. Show what you did, so we can help fixing it.

Comment: font-awesome is a *font*, not an icon.  The font awesome CSS file is going to be pointing to these assets.  Are you unable to go to the font-awesome website and download the library for use locally or on your own server?

Comment: Robaddy, do you mean by "assets" in this case a particular folder? I have downloaded the fonts and they are on my server. I'm trying to point to them from style.css but it is just not working. When I look inside the folder, there is lots of stuff and one folder full of icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy all the font files (NOT THE CSS FILE) from your font awesome folder (EOT files, WOFF files, etc) to a folder named `fonts`which should be in the same directory as where your html file is located in and copy the font-awesome.css file to your css folder.
Then keep this line on your  section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I don't want to paste that link into my head tag, because one thing I want to do is increase page speed and doing that would decrease speed. I want to store the fonts needed locally on my server and call the fonts from my css.

Comment: Can you add a ; to the fourth line of the above css and see if that helps: `/ *  Font Awesome 4.1.0 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome*/
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; <--`

Comment: Thanks for your commitment Andrew :) I'm sad to say it still doesn't work. I changed the folder name to fonts, and I can see the reason for this. There is no font-awesome.css file in the font-awesome folder, instead there is a css file named flaticon.css. I copied this to my css folder, uploaded it and changed href part of your suggestion to call for css/flacticon.css, but it didn't work. There is also a font.awesome.min.css file that is created of the big file where the code that I use on the site is stored. I tried to call for this file also from my head HTML section but it doesn't work...

Comment: Is the fonts folder inside the css folder by any chance??

Comment: No Andrew, the fonts folder is in root of public_html where everything else also is located. I'm suspecting now that the font-awesome library I downloaded is different than what was originally pointed to with @import command. I looked up the file names from the font-awesome icon folder and they were different than in my css. I called upon them differently, changes some html and could actually get few to show up, but not the way they should. Still trying to solve this :)

Comment: Glad to hear you're making progress in solving this :) Just remove every f-awesome font file, css file and the import and redo the font awesome integration from scratch. That way, there's less chances of errors and hiccups :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `@font-face` rule is missing the `src` styles that specify where the font files are:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src:
      url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src:
      url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'),
      url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'),
      url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Now I know what happened: for some reason the http is removed when I paste the code in the comments window. Happened again above. But it is there!

Comment: @KimWist: The URL that you are using is looking inside the `public_html` folder, but the font file isn't there. I tried without that folder too, but it's not there either. You have to check where the font files actually are, and set the URL to match.

Comment: @KimWist: Where do you have the font files? Right now it looks in the folder `font-awesome` at the same level as `public_html`. First make sure that you can reach them by using the address directly in the browser. Then you can put the URL in the CSS. (The version number at the end of the URL is just a cache breaker by the way, the server ignores the parameter.)

Comment: I renamed the font-awesome folder yesterday to simply "fonts". It is the root in the public_html folder. It can be reached from the browser, and was reachable before also, this is not the problem.

Comment: @KimWist: What is the address? I can't seem to reach the font files.

Comment: Go to http://www.kimwist.com/fonts/flaticon.html this file is only one inside the folder, but opens up in your browser. Then there are folders with icons and svg, eot and other files.

Comment: @KimWist: That file isn't reachable, I get a HTTP 404. However, I can reach for example http://www.kimwist.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0 so that's the URL you could use in the CSS. The URL `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0` that you have in the CSS right now also works. There just isn't any element using the font right now, so it's not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody the problem is now solved. I had a wrong font-awesome library. I downloaded it again from the actual site and it was much smaller. I didn't place a link to font-awesome.css in my header, instead I copied all font-awesome rules that I needed to my style.css and got rid of one css file like this. All the eot, svf, ttf etc. files are in fonts folder and style.css in css folder. With the correct library everything works now fine.

There is one more minor issue but it is browser based and I will open another discussion about that.

Thank you everybody for contributing.
Kim

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem Kim :)